# Claims that fully formal proofs are impossible to write down

Tags: philosophy-of-science, mathematical-logic

It is sometimes asserted that human-readable mathematical proofs that we construct and publish are just informal approximations to the gold standard, which is a completely formal proof in a formal language.  The formal proof is supposed to be the real McCoy, the pinnacle of Platonic perfection, which our messy informal proofs try their best to gesture toward.

I seem to recall reading criticisms (of the above assertion) that focused on the enormous size of formal proofs, claiming that they were so large and unwieldy that it would be impossible to write them down in full. If they are so large that we cannot actually produce them or even properly grasp them in our minds, then can we legitimately claim that such fictions are what proofs really are, or strive to be?

Although I feel that I have encountered the above criticism many times, I am having trouble finding an explicit example of someone making this kind of argument in print. The closest thing I have found is A. R. D. Mathias's essay, [A term of length 4,523,659,424,929](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ardm/inefff.pdf), which discusses a system for set theory due to Bourbaki, and emphasizes the gigantic size of even very simple terms in the system.  However, Mathias's criticism is narrowly focused on Bourbaki's system in particular, and he does not take the additional step of arguing that *all* fully formal proofs are too long to write down, and (thus) cannot in any sense be what mathematical proofs really are, or aspire to be.

In the introduction to the book *18 Unconventional Essays on the Nature of Mathematics*, Reuben Hersh recalls the distinction that he made in his earlier book (*What Is Mathematics, Really?*) between formal proof and "an argument accepted as conclusive by the present-day mathematical community," and mentions the Flyspeck Project to produce a completely formal proof of the Kepler Conjecture.  Hersh writes, "I do not know anyone who thinks either that this project can be completed, or that even if claimed to be complete it would be universally accepted as a convincing proof of Kepler's conjecture."  What Hersh writes here is close to what I am looking for; on the question of what proofs really are, he clearly favors informal proof over formal proof, and he expresses some skepticism about formal proofs that is related to their size.  But he still stops short of arguing that formal proofs of nontrivial mathematical theorems are simply too large and complicated to ever instantiate in the real world.

Is there a better published reference for the argument that (1) formal proofs of nontrivial theorems are intrinsically so huge that they will forever remain figments of our imagination, and (2) therefore we should be skeptical of the role of formal proofs in the justification of mathematical knowledge?  I'm imagining that such a reference would likely date from the mid-20th century, since nowadays the existence of computerized proof assistants makes it much harder to argue that fully formal proofs of nontrivial theorems can never be instantiated in the real world.

Comment: It would very strange if somebody claimed that **all** formal proofs are impossible to write. (Russel and Whitehead, I think, we're doing exactly this with **some** formal proofs.) Maybe the claim was that it is impossible to write  formal proofs of all extant mathematical results?

Comment: @MoisheKohan If you read carefully what I wrote, I referred to formal proofs of *nontrivial theorems*. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Oh, never mind then...

Comment: My own reaction is that it is apparently ever-more possible to have proof assistants help write full, formal proofs of non-trivial things... but unless I learn their special language, and have confidence in all the software underpinning it, I'll not find those formalized proofs "persuasive". In particular, I'd not be able to personally/directly _confirm_.

Comment: @paulgarrett In case it's not clear, I'm trying to track the *history* of the debate, not engage in the debate itself. This is the HSM SE site, after all.

Comment: @TimothyChow, yes, I do understand, but/and I do also think that some of the problems in accurate history involve accurate framing of the question. :)

Comment: One aspect of the story is that proof assistants allow the user to write proofs in an intermediate format, sufficiently clear so that the computer is able to rewrite them as a fully formal. For example, the computer is able to complete by itself some arguments, to make some computations, rewriting, etc. At Bourbaki's time, this would have been done on paper and the Russell/Whitehead book indicates the enormous size of the enterprise!

Comment: As @paulgarrett indicates, the activity of a mathematician is not only to create, write, tell proofs, it is also to understand the “mathematical nature”. If you're given a 1TB USB key that, you're told so, provides a proof of the Riemann hypothesis, or of P=NP, that does not tell you much about the underlying maths.

Comment: I don't have access to verify, but you may want to look at Tymoczko, Thomas. “The Four-Color Problem and Its Philosophical Significance.” The Journal of Philosophy, vol. 76, no. 2, 1979, pp. 57–83. His argument concerned the non-surveyability of the non-formal proof of the FCT, but he may mention in passing the surveyability of formal proofs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would you be thinking of this passage in the introduction of Bourbaki's *Théorie des ensembles*, page I 10? ([Google preview](https://books.google.fi/books?id=VDGifaOQogcC&lpg=SA1-PA10&ots=C18MupGocn&pg=SA1-PA10#v=onepage&q&f=false))

> Si la mathématique formalisée était aussi simple que le jeu d’échecs,
> une fois décrit le langage formalisé que nous avons choisi, il n’y
> aurait plus qu’à rédiger nos demonstrations dans ce langage ... un tel
> projet est absolument irréalisable; la moindre demonstration du debut
> de la Théorie des Ensembles exigerait déjà des centaines de signes
> pour être complètement formalisée.

Same passage in its English translation ([Google preview](https://books.google.it/books?id=IL-SI67hjI4C&lpg=PA351&hl=fi&pg=PA10#v=onepage&q&f=false)), boldface emphasis mine:

> If formalized mathematics were as simple as the game of chess, then
> once our chosen formalized language had been described there would
> remain only the task of **writing out our proofs in this language**
> ... such a project is **absolutely unrealizable** : the tiniest proof
> at the beginning of the Theory of Sets would already **require several
> hundreds of signs** for its complete formalization.

Bourbaki goes on to claim that it is necessary to use lots of *abbreviations* to make the language more manageable than the formalized language, and any mathematician worth his salt will be convinced that such things can be taken as shorthand descriptions of the formal thing.  And that the abbreviation rules themselves must be informal, because otherwise they will be too complicated to be useful.

It *seems* to me that this is meant to be a general statement against the longhand use *any* formal system, not just the particular one they have chosen in the book. (Literally it says "our chosen formalized language" but that might mean "whatever language we have chosen to formalize, ...").

This passage is discussed by Thomas Hales in ''Developments of formal proofs'' ([arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.6474) 2014; see page 15: "Bourbaki objected that formal proofs are too long"). Bourbaki's words seem widely cited, e.g. ["require several hundreds of signs"](https://www.google.com/search?channel=nrow5&client=firefox-b-d&q=%22require%20several%20hundreds%20of%20signs%22), so that might also give some leads.

Comment: Thanks for this pointer. I had taken Bourbaki to be saying only that abbreviations were necessary, but hadn't realized that they regarded abbreviations as necessarily informal. I will take a closer look at this.

Comment: I'm looking at Bourbaki now. He does say that if we use a language with abbreviations, "we no longer have the certainty that the passage from one of these languages to the other can be made in purely mechanical fashion." And this: "formalized mathematics cannot in practice be written down in full." This is about as explicit as one could hope for, so I'm accepting this answer.

Comment: One thing that puzzles me is how definitive they meant that statement to be ("cannot in practice be written down in full"). Is it an observation of the current state of affairs back then, or is it a statement of necessity. Of course that passage is over 50 years old. It might not have been clear if computers will make "formal abbreviations" practical.

Comment: There is some discussion of this point [on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/414847). Abbreviations are absolutely crucial, so a lot depends on how one views them. Bourbaki says that abbreviations cannot with "certainty" be "made in purely mechanical fashion." This to me sounds like a claim that even with computers, one is in trouble. Of course, Bourbaki may not have thought too hard about the matter since he wasn't trying to *prove* that full formalization of mathematics is impossible in practice.

Answer (score 4):

In Donald Mackenzie's article, [The Automation of Proof: A Historical and Sociological Exploration](https://web.archive.org/web/20160910165845/http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4860/2012fa/MacKenzie-TheAutomationOfProof.pdf), I found some statements by P. Nidditch that come close to what I have been looking for.

> In the whole literature of mathematics there is not a
> single valid proof in the logical sense … The number
> of original books or papers on mathematics in the
> course of the last 300 years is of the order of 106; in
> these, the number of even close approximations to really valid proofs is of the order of 101 … In the relatively few places where a mathematician has seriously tried to give a valid proof, he has always overlooked at least some of the rules of inference and
> logical theorems of which he has made use and to
> which he has made no explicit reference.

As for whether full proofs could *in principle* be written down, Nidditch wrote:

> Since no mathematician has ever constructed a complete proof, his reputed capacity for doing so has no better status than an occult quality.

Answer (score 0):

Do we say the presentation in Whitehead & Russell is not fully formal?

[image: picture]

Comment: This is potentially a long discussion, but the short version is: (1) their theorems are all pretty much trivial; (2) much of it is not in fact fully formal by modern standards, as (for example) Goedel pointed out; (3) when people checked the more formal (propositional) part of it later on with computers, they found some errors. For the present discussion, (1) is the most relevant. The main question is whether proofs of substantive theorems that research mathematicians actually care about (as opposed to "toy" theorems) can be made fully formal.